How can I keep anonymous user account perpetually open on Apex 19.2 running on Oracle DB 21c XE?
I have an apex 19.2 running on oracle db 21c XE which i recently upgraded from the 19c XE db. Since the upgrade, I have needed to run the statement alter user anonymous account unlock; for it work. When I query the account status, I find it in locked state and I don't know what keeps on locking the account.

Any ideas on how I can keep the account open indefinitely?

Alter the user's assigned profile or alter the profile it's assigned to.

@JeffHolt How do I do that exactly?

I decided to use ORDS instead of EPG and host the app using Apache Tomcat and the issue was resolved.
